# Get subject and issuer information from the X509*

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl

I am in process of verifying a client certificate on server.

I have used the SSL_CTX_set_verify and have a valid callback API inside which i am validating the client certificate for expiry date and few other parameters.I need to extract the 'Issued By' and 'Issued To' values of the client certificate.

The call back function is like this

```
int certificateVerificationCallBack(int preverify_ok, X509_STORE_CTX *ctx)
{
    X509* cert = X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert(ctx);
}
```

I am getting the client certificate details filled into the X509 pointer and am able to get the expiry date too(straight forward access). But i am not able to figure out what OpenSSL API to use to get the 'issued by' and 'issued to'.

Comment: Also see [SSL/TLS Client](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client) on the OpenSSL wiki. It dumps a number of the X509 fields.

Answer (score 5):

If you want the subject name and issuer name of the certificate, you need to use the `X509_get_subject_name()` and `X509_get_issuer_name()` APIs. These take the X509 pointer and return the respective names.

More Info can be obtained [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/x509.html) and [here](https://zakird.com/2013/10/13/certificate-parsing-with-openssl)

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Although to extract the actual string one needs to do something like below -


char *subj = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(err_cert), NULL, 0);
char *issuer = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_issuer_name(err_cert), NULL, 0);